On a possible isomorphism from a spectral sequence coming from derived tensor-hom adjunction
Let $M,N,X$ be modules over a commutative ring $R$. We have the derived tensor-hom adjunction  $$\mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(M\otimes_R^{\mathbf L} N,X)\cong \mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(M,\mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(N,X))$$
Now assume there exists an integer $s\ge 0$ such that $\text{Ext}_R^i(N,X)=0$ for all $i\neq s$. Then, $\mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(N,X)\cong \text{Ext}_R^s(N,X)[-s]$. So,  $$\mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(M\otimes_R^{\mathbf L} N,X)\cong \mathbf R\text{Hom}_R(M,\text{Ext}_R^s(N,X))[-s]$$
Now assume there exists an integer $g\ge 0$ such that $\text{Ext}^i_R(\text{Tor}^R_q(M,N), X)=0$ for all $i\neq g$ and all $q>0$. Then, is there some spectral sequence argument which would allow me to conclude $$\text{Ext}^g_R(\text{Tor}^R_q(M,N), X)\cong \text{Ext}_R^{g+q+s}(M, \text{Ext}_R^s(N,X))$$ for all $q>0$ ?
